# How to get shopee item selling price from api

Tags: php, json, web-scraping

im currently leaning to do a crawler in shopee, so far i have an URL calling search and get item detail
`$url = 'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=relevancy&keyword=' . $search . '&limit=' . $totalSearch . '&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2';`

and loop the itemId and ShopId to get item detail
`$url = 'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/item/get?itemid=' . $itemID . '&shopid=' . $shopID;`
`$curl->get($url);`

but i realize the result return
`echo $result->item->price` is a very long number (9 digits format) instead of the item actual price (actual price is 1999)

I wish to know the result is in other currency or it is an priceId need to call another api to get the actual price

below are part of the result

```
    ...
        "has_low_fulfillment_rate": false,
        "price": 248840963,
        "shop_location": "P",
        "tier_variations": [...],
        "min_purchase_limit": 0,
    ...
```

Comment: `echo $result->item->price` <-- Add a newline, such as a `'<br />'` or a `PHP_EOL`, there may be all prices already, but without new lines, it's just a big number

Comment: If what @Cid has said does not apply you're probably dealing with a price stored as a integer. You'll need to dig deeper on the documentation, namely to check the precision of the stored prices. Usually you'll need to divide the integer value by said precision.

Comment: @Cid the result return in json format, it is a 9 digit long format but the item price is only 1,999

Comment: @nitrin0 i have searched a few seller selling the same item, all of its price are same (1,999) but the item->price all return in different number (all still in 9 digit format but first digit range from 1-9)

Comment: Could you paste an example (of a real price and the one you get). Like i said above it seems you're dealing with a integer that you'll need to divide to get the decimal value. Usually that integer is stored by multiplying the decimal value by 10,100,1000... and such (example: 1,999 can be stored as 1999 by multiplying 1000).

Comment: i have added the part of the result including the price, the price return doesnt look like multiply of 100 or 100 but just random number.

Comment: If that's the case this is a misunderstanding of what the values are and/or mean, not a code issue. I assume they have documentation on their API's. Still, looking into examples like this [one](https://shopee.sg/api/v2/item/get?itemid=2590867516&shopid=165420215) makes me think some sort of integer precision logic is involved.

Comment: I've tried a bit the API and there's a member `currency`. You'll have to use the value in it to get the currect price in the currency you want